# Ubuntu: Postfix and Cyrus expecting saslauthd PID file in different locations

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, cyrus, pid, saslauthd

I'm running postfix and cyrus in parallel on my server, as far as I understand this is a quite common think to do. Both daemons use sasl authorization. However, postfix is looking for the saslauthd pid file in /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd and cyrus is looking in /var/run/saslauthd.

Now, I can just create soft links from the postfix directory to the cyrus directory and everything works fine. Weirdly enough it doesn't work the other way around. Anyhow, I don't feel like this is a legitimate solution to the problem.

I tried to find any configuration files where I can set the sasl pid directory for cyrus and postfix, couldn't really find any though.
Is it possible to have two different pid files for saslauthd in two different directorys?

Thanks, Stefan

Answer (score 4):

Postfix wants its files under `/var/spool/postfix` because that's where all the daemons `chroot` into.  You *could* turn off `chroot` for the daemons which need access to that file, but I wouldn't recommend it.  The `chroot` issue is why the symlinking worked when you linked *into* the `chroot`, but not when you linked out.

I'd be mightily surprised if there wasn't an option in Cyrus to set the location where it writes its dynamic files; I haven't used Cyrus since the 1.x days, so I'm of no help there.

Comment: A thanks, that at least explains that linking behaviour.